# Restrict access to a post once it is tagged as a given status

Tags: user-roles, post-status

I am trying to make any post that has been tagged and saved with a certain status non-editable by editor users.

I am using a custom plugin that extends the status' to include subbing, however, at present I am just trying to get the functionality there so am using the publish status.

Can anyone see what's wrong with my code below?

As far as i can tell, I am assigning `publish` status and `editor` user to variables, checking if these are true and then removing editing capabilities, then hooking this in before the post is published.

```
// Restrict editors making changes to articles after tagged published
function restrict($new_status, $post){
    $pub = get_post_status($post) == 'publish';
    $editor = get_role('editor');
    if ($new_status == $pub && (current_user_can('edit_post'))){
        remove_cap($editor, 'edit_posts');
    }
}
add_action('publish_post', 'restrict', 10, 2);
```

Comment: But you are removing capabilities globally, not just for a single, particular post?

Comment: Ah you are right, thanks for pointing that out! Can you see anything else wrong?

Comment: TheDeadMedic's answer looks pretty solid to me, but you may be interested in: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124868/create-a-mostly-read-only-cpt/124893?s=1|5.5060#124893

Comment: Or: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/94776/21376

Comment: Thanks a lot for those I will look through those too, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't remove the capability - this will make all editors unable to edit all posts. Instead, use a filter to conditionally determine if the post can be edited:

```
function wpse_187738_map_meta_cap( $caps, $cap, $user_ID, $args ) {
    if ( $cap === 'edit_post' && $args && ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) /** Only proceed for non-administrators */ ) {
        $post_id = $args[0];
        if ( has_tag( 'tag_slug_or_id', $post_id ) )
            $caps[] = 'not_allowed';
    }

    return $caps;
}

add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'wpse_187738_map_meta_cap', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! Would you mind just explaining the part in the conditional where $args is parsed without being assigned anything? I'm still very much learning PHP/wordpress structure

Comment: Read up on [filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters). The arguments are passed to the function from the filter caller, in this case [`map_meta_cap`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/map_meta_cap)